# While clipping a Raster generated from SCP plugin (classification) all the colors are vanished in the end output and the raster generated is in B/W

Tags: qgis, clip, raster-conversion, land-classification, scp

I have done all the LULC classification using SCP plugin. after completing my classification, I wanted to clip the raster using a Shape File. But when I do it, the colors are vanished in the output clipped raster. The raster generated is in Black and White. Help me to fix this.

[image: Shape file on Original Raster]

[image: Generated raster after clipping using yellow colored shape file]

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the color raster layer in the layers panel and copy the style from it, then right click on the gray raster layer and paste the style there.